# TCL Regexp Explanation

Tags: regex, tcl

What does the below regexp mean. I could see that some value has to get assigned to "z"

`regexp ${a}(.+?)($x) $y NULL p1 p2 p3 z p5`

but what are these `p1`, `p2` etc..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know anything about TCL but this could help you http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm

Answer (score 2):

First, read [the documentation for the TCL regexp command](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/regexp.htm).

Armed with that information, we can deconstruct the command:

- `regexp`: the command.
- `${a}(.+?)($x)`: the pattern. You'll need to figure out the value of the `a` and `x` variables to get the full regex.
- `$y`: the string that needs to be matched
- `NULL`: the full match will be stored in the variable `NULL`. It seems the program doesn't care about this value.
- `p1 p2 p3 z p5`: The matches of the subgroups of the regex will be stored in these variables. Apparently the regex is expected to have five subgroups. `z` will receive the match of the fourth subgroup.